# How to use ionicModal Methods?

Tags: ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

Is there anybody can explain that how to use ionicModal methods like **initialize(options)**, **isShown()** described on [doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/controller/ionicModal/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initialize method is the constructor used internally. That bit is basically showing you the methods you can pass [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/) to the `fromTemplate` and `fromTemplateUrl` methods on the $iconicModal service.

The other methods like `isShown` are to be used on the *instance* of the modal.

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('my-modal.html', { <- this hash goes to initialize
  scope: $scope,  
  animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal) {
 $scope.modal = modal; <- this is the instance to call "isShown"/etc on
});
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit methods like isShown, show() please? Maybe an example will be better, thanks.

Comment: They are the methods on the instance. Look at the documentation here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/